# How can I display the number minutes, hours, or days from the amount of seconds that I have in C++?

Tags: c++

```
//courseID:CIS165-006HY
//name: Omar Barrera
//Prof. Wang
//Assignment#4
//Due by 03/07/2020

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int 86400 seconds = 1 day,
int 3600 seconds = 1 hour,
int 60 seconds = 1 minute,
int number;

cout << "Enter amount of Seconds" << endl;
cin >>number>>endl;



if (number >= 86400)
    cout<<number<<"day(s)"<<endl;
else if (86400 >= number >= 3600)
    cout<<number<<"hour(s)"<<endl;
else if (3600 >= number >= 60)
    cout<<number<<"minute(s)"<<endl;
else (number < 60)
    cout<<number<<"seconds"<<endl:

return 0;
}
```

The error that popped up in my compiler was

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:12:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
>  int 86,400 seconds = 1 day,
>      ^~
> main.cpp:18:7: error: ‘number’ was not declared in this scope
>  cin >>number>>endl;
> ```

Comment: You need to review how to declare variables.  `int 86400 seconds` is not a valid variable declaration.  You may want to make them as comments.

Comment: You could use math:  `const int days = number / 86400;`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the lines that generate errors?

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't work like maths

```
else if (86400 >= number >= 3600)
```

should be

```
else if (86400 >= number && number >= 3600)
```

Comment: You may want to also point out the invalid variable declarations that follow `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change your logic to use more math:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int number = 0;

    cout << "Enter amount of Seconds" << endl;
    cin >>number>>endl;

    const double days = number / 86400.0;
    const double hours = number / 3600.0;
    const double minutes = number / 60.0;

    std::cout << "Days:    " << days    << "\n";
    std::cout << "Hours:   " << hours   << "\n";
    std::cout << "Minutes: " << minutes << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I eliminated the invalid variable declarations that followed `main`.

I also moved the calculations to after the `number` is input from the User.